# Как залить изменения на GitHub в репозиторий, который создан не мной?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, github, git-commit, repository

Суть вопроса: есть проект на GitHub с кодом, залит другим человеком. Мне нужно сделать часть своего задания в этом проекте и закоммитить сделанные мной изменения в этот проект. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать. В свои репозитории умею вносить изменения и заливать, а вот с чужим репозиторием проблема. Буду рад любой помощи. Спасибо

Comment: Вы можете также попробовать пообщаться с автором репозитория, чтобы он вам прислал приглашение для разработки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы хотите влезть в чужой репозиторий и что-то там поменять? Это так не работает (:

Читаем [документацию](https://help.github.com/articles/about-pull-requests/). Если в двух словах.

1. Вы форкаете чей-то репозиторий. Работаете теперь со своим репозиторием (копией оригинального).
2. Делаете изменения в нём.
3. Пушите изменения.
4. У вас на странице вашего форка на гитхабе появится кнопка для созданий пул реквеста.
5. Если автор примет ваш пул реквест, то ваши изменения попадут в его репозиторий.

Comment: 2.1 Убеждаетесь в работоспособности изменений.

Comment: 2.2 Пишете Unit тесты

Comment: Спасибо большое, немного неправильно задал вопрос, но ответ получил))